# Determine if $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to S_4:(1,0)\to(1,2,3),(0,1)\to(2,3,4)$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Is it even possible for $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to be homomorphic to $S_4$, since $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite? I know I have to show that $\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b)$, but I don't really understand how the given map works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$(0,1)+(1,0)=(1,0)+(0,1)$$

The actual idea is to assume that there *is* a homomorphism meeting this description (since, if it exists, then it will be unique). You must then determine if it is well-defined.

Incidentally, there *is* a homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to S_4.$ For example, $1\mapsto(1,2,3,4)$ works. This is neither one-to-one (obviously) nor onto, but it does yield a unique homomorphism.

Comment: But what does it mean that $(1,0)\to(1,2,3),(0,1)\to(2,3,4)$?

Comment: Ah! What it means (for example) is that the homomorphism sends the ordered pair $(1,0)$ to the permutation $(1,2,3).$ Put in (perhaps) more familiar terms, they are saying that $$\phi\bigl((1,0)\bigr)=(1,2,3)$$ and $$\phi\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=(2,3,4).$$

Comment: Oh! So it is only defined for those two pairs?

Comment: Well, since those two elements generate $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z,$ then stating which elements of $\Bbb S_4$ those two elements are sent to will uniquely determine a homomorphism on all of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z,$ *if* there is *any* homomorphism meeting those conditions.

Comment: Does (the most recent version of) my comment help at all?

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now

Comment: How would I use the homomorphism property with this though?

Comment: Well, if you have any questions, or if you just want to run any proof attempts by someone, feel free!

Comment: So far I have:
$$\phi[(1,0)]\phi[(0,1)]=(1,2,3)(2,3,4)$$
$$=(2,3,4,1)$$
$$\phi[(1,0)+(0,1)]=\phi(1,1)$$
But i cant get the final step

Comment: The hint is $(0,1) + (1,0) = (1,0) + (0,1)$, it's not $(1,0) + (0,1) = (1,1)$ @MattG

Comment: Also, you should note, @Matt, that $(1,2,3)(2,3,4)\neq(2,3,4,1).$

Comment: so I have to prove that $\phi[(1,0)(01)]=\phi[(0,1)(1,0)]$?

Comment: Well, I'd start by figuring out what $\phi\bigl((1,0)+(0,1)\bigr)$ and $\phi\bigl((0,1)+(1,0)\bigr)$ are, first. Then you should proceed based on what you find out.

Comment: But wouldnt that just prove or disprove commutativity?

Comment: Commutativity of what, exactly?

Comment: @Matt: At any rate, it's past my bedtime. Try what I suggested, see what you can figure out, and I'll do what I can to answer any other questions tomorrow.

Comment: @Matt: Did you make any progress? What did you come up with for $\phi\bigl((1,0)+(0,1)\bigr)$ and $\phi\bigl((0,1)+(1,0)\bigr)$?

Comment: @Matt: Since we assumed that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we *should* have (for example) that $$\phi\bigl((1,0)+(0,1)\bigr)=\phi\bigl((1,0)\bigr)\phi\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=(1,2,3)(2,3,4),$$ but what is the simplified form of $(1,2,3)(2,3,4)$?

Comment: Would it be (1,2,4)?

Comment: @MattG: Let's continue this conversation [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30753/discussion-on-answer-by-cameron-buie-determine-if-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-to), shall we?